# If ... is not an int {

Tags: java, int

I am trying to get the program to recognize if an int is not entered .

I have seen everything from:

```
   if  (v % 1)
```

to

```
    parseInt();
```

but they aren't working for me .

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LinearSlopeFinder {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        double x1, y1, x2, y2, n1, equation, constant = 0 ;
        double slope, slope1, slopeAns;
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("    What is the first set of cordinants? example: x,y ... ");
        String coordinate1 = myScanner.nextLine();

        //below is what i am referring to 


        if (coordinate1 != int ){    // if it is a double or String 
            System.out.println("Sorry, you must use whole numbers.What is the first set of cordinants? example: x,y ... ");
            System.out.print("    What is the first set of cordinants? example: x,y ... ");
            String coordinate1 = myScanner.nextLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking that a value is a primitive like that won't work. Java will not be able to compare a value to a type in such a way.

One method is to take advantage of the static function [`Integer.parseInt(String s)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) to see if an appropriate int value has been entered. Notice that it throws a `NumberFormatException`. If you can take advantage of this fact, you can obtain whether or not an integer was provided from a function.

```
try {
   //Attempt the parse here
} catch (...) {
   //Not a proper integer
}
```

A second technique (since you're already taking advantage of the `Scanner` class) is to use the `Scanner` [methods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) `hasNextInt()` and `nextInt()` to determine if:

1. The `Scanner` has a new integer in the stream
2. Get the actual integer value off of the stream

An example usage would be:

```
if (myScanner.hasNextInt()) {
   int totalAmount = myScanner.nextInt();
   // do stuff here
} else {
   //Int not provided
}
```

As you mentioned in your update, this is all fine and good when input from the `Scanner` is *delimited* by spaces. By default, Scanner delimits values within the stream by spaces. What happens when you've got a different delimiter (ex: "," or "//" etc) that separates two unique values logically on the stream?

The solution to that is to modify the delimiter that the `Scanner` is using. There is a method called [`useDelimiter(String pattern)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29) which allows you to specify how values will be separated logically within the stream. It's very useful for cases like what you're dealing within (or any cases where spaces do not delimit the values).

The usage will look something like this:

```
Scanner myScanner = ...; # Get this how you normally would
String delimiter = ...;  # Decide what the separator will be
myScanner.useDelimiter(delimiter); # Tell the Scanner to use this separator
```

There is a good example of this within the `Scanner` API (see the first link on `Scanner` I included for that example) that describes how this is used. I suggest checking that out, and it'll come together very nicely for you (I believe).

Comment: 'Syntax error on token "int", invalid Expression' is what it tells me

Comment: Good catch. My mistake (late and I'm not checking my work carefully). Obviously, when creating a variable, make sure to name it. I've corrected the error now.

Comment: wow , im dumb . 
forgot to mention .... The Answer will never be an int because the input is in the form of x,y including the "," so 2,3

Comment: You can fix that with a Scanner too believe it or not! I'll update my answer with a little explanation.

Comment: BTW, you should check out alf's answer. He's got a very good piece of advice at the end of his answer!

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution, so that you had choice: in [JLS  §3.10.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html#48282) you can read what integer can be. Putting the definition in a regexp form, you have:

```
// input s
if (s.matches("(?i)[+-]?(0|[1-9][0-9]*|0[x][0-9a-f]+|0[0-7]+)L?")) { /* do something */}
```

The downside would be, you add a verbose definition of a number in your code—Java could do that for you. The bonus, though, is that your case with `2,3` is easily addressed:

```
String intLiteral = "[+-]?(0|[1-9][0-9]*|0[x][0-9a-f]+|0[0-7]+)L?";
// input s
if (s.matches("(?i)" + intLiteral + "," + intLiteral)) { /* do something */}
```

(things are not going to be that easy, because you'd probably like strings like `2, 3` valid, too—but I'll leave it with you.)

Returning to the commonly used solution and your comment about `2,3`, you must get into habit of separating problems: you already know several ways to check whether a string contains integer or not. What you can do now is to leave this problem alone and address your commas:

```
    String s = "2,3";
    String[] parts = s.split(","); // here we deal with commas

    try {
        // now when we have parts, deal with parts separately
        System.out.println("First:  " + Integer.parseInt(parts[0]));
        System.out.println("Second: " + Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("There was a problem, you know: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Integer.parseInt(yourInt)`, but then you have to catch the error that is thrown if you do not receive an integer, like this:

```
try {
  Integer.parseInt(yourInt);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  // do something that indicates to the user that an int was not given.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (coordinate1 != int)
```

won't work, because you're comparing a value to a type. This code shouldn't even compile.

Use:

```
try {
    int integer = Integer.parseInt(value);
} catch (NumbumberFormatException e) {
    // Not an integer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this model:

```
Integer result = null;
try {
    result = Integer.valueOf(input);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
if (result != null) {
    // An integer was entered
}
```

Integer.valueOf will throw an exception for numbers with deciamls, so you shouldn't have any problems. I'm using the Integer class vs int so that it can be set to null. Using -1 means that -1 cannot be entered.

Answer (score 0):

One method you could try using is a new method. Here's one I use for getting integer inputs:

```
public static int getIntInput(Scanner s) { // Just put your scanner into here so that the method can read inputs without creating a new scanner each time
    System.out.print("Enter int here: ");
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("You must enter a valid Integer literal.");
        return getIntInput(s);            // Note that this line just repeats the try statement all over again.
    }
```

If the input is an integer, it will return an int; otherwise, it tries again. Note: add a counter so that the code doesn't break if someone sets their lunch bag on your enter key.