# Splitting up a string in Java

Tags: java, string, substring

Can anyone advise on an issue that's been bugging me? I have a Java .jar file which returns a string from a method made up as follows:

```
integer integer integer block_of_text
```

That is three integers which may be positive or negative, each separated by single spaces, and then another space before a block of text which may consist of any characters but which should not contain carriage returns. Now I suppose I can read a substring up to the space character for each of the initial integers and then simply read the remaining text in one go.

I should add that the block of text is not to be broken down regardless of what it contains.

But can anyone suggest a better alternative?

Thanks to the respondents. This has saved me a headache!

Comment: Can block_of_text contains newline characters? More particularly, '\n' on Linux/OS X, or '\r\n' on Windows. I assume yes because you said any characters could exist there.

Comment: block of text may contain spaces?

Comment: Carriage returns and newlines - no. Spaces - yes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the form of [`String#split(regex,limit)` which takes a limit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)):

```
String s = "123 456 789 The rest of the string";
String ss[] = s.split(" ", 4);
// ss = {"123", "456", "789", "The rest of the string"};
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of using split like this.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `String.split` with space as a separator, and set a limit of 4:

```
String[] result = s.split(" ", 4);
```

You could also use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). This will not only split the text, but also parse the integers to `int`. Depending on whether you need the three integers as `int` or `String`, you might find this more convenient:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
int value1 = scanner.nextInt();
int value2 = scanner.nextInt();
int value3 = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.skip(" ");
String text = scanner.nextLine();
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/hyqFZ#view_edit_box).

Answer (score 3):

One simple way (since you said there won't be newlines in block_of_text) is to use a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). It is a tool to break up input based upon a certain delimited, and return appropriate types back to you. For example, you can use the methods `hasNextInt()` and `nextInt()` to check for an integer in the input, and to actually pull it from the stream.

For example:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // Arg could be a String, another InputStream, etc
int[] values = new int[3];
values[0] = scanner.nextInt();
values[1] = scanner.nextInt();
...
String description = scanner.nextLine();
```

You could use this until you've exhausted the input stream, and begin using the values as you need.

Here are more details on how to use `Scanner`: [If ... is not an int {](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857780/if-is-not-an-int/7857813#7857813)

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to split the string is by using the `split` method.

```
String gen = "some texts here";
String spt[] = gen.split(" ");  //This will split the string gen around the spaces and stores them into the given string array
```

To remove the integers according to your question, start the array index from 3.
I hope this would help.